# Registering and updating application properties using JMX

Tags: java, properties, jmx

I have to access some application through an mbean so that I can change its application properties.  Now i think this can be done in two ways:

1. First, either I ask the developer of that application to register all the application properties in an arraylist which my mbean will access.
2. Secondly, if there is any other way, such that the developer will only need to register editable properties and still my mbean can access both readable/editable(r/w) application properties.

Now since I don't know where these application properties are stored in the JVM, is there a way to implement my second point so that the mbean will just need to access that object and it will get all application properties?

Comment: Please try to express better your question. It's hard to read and understand a bulk of unformated text...

Comment: What do you mean by "property"?  You talking system property or object field or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have some contradicting requirements here.

1. You want to change minimal code in the application.
2. You want to be cause to expose all properties for read and/or write.
3. You may or may not be talking about `System.getProperty(...)`.  If not then I guess you are talking about just fields in various objects.

There are (at least) two ways of doing this.  Without knowing how you are exporting the mbeans from the source code right now, I can't tailor my answer to your specific config.  My answer will instead show how you might use my [SimpleJMX package](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) to expose your properties.

If you are talking about `System.getProperty(...)` then you could write a JMX mbean that could query any property and return the value:

```
@JmxOperation(description = "Query for property")
public String queryForProperty(String name) {
   return System.getProperty(name);
}
```

If, instead, you need to export of fields from some list of objects then you are going to either have to add annotations to each fields you are exporting or you are going to have to write beans that export the fields through delegation.  I see no easy way and I know of no package that will easily export a series of objects for you without some sort of information about what is to be exported and how.

Using SimpleJMX, you can export a field by annotating either the field or the get method:

```
@JmxAttributeField(description = "Number of hits in the cache")
private int hitCount;
...

// this can also be specified as @JmxAttributeMethod on the getter/setter methods
@JmxAttributeMethod(description = "Number of misses in the cache")
private int getMissCount() {
    return missCount;
}
```

The `@JmxAttributeField` supports a `isWritable = true` to allow the value to be set by JMX.  You can also annotation the setter with `@JmxAttributeMethod` to make it writable.

If you don't want to add annotations to each of your classes, then you are going to have to write some sort of JMX container class that exports the values through delegation:

```
 public class JmxPublisher {
     private Class1 object1;
     private Class2 object2;
     ...
     public JmxPublisher(Class1 object1, Class2 object2) {
         this.object1 = object1;
         this.object2 = object2;
         ...
     }

     @JmxAttributeMethod(description = "Number of hits in the cache")
     public int getClass1HitCount() {
        return object1.getHitCount();
     }
     @JmxAttributeMethod(description = "Shutdown the background thread")
     public void setClass2Shutdown(boolean shutdown) {
        return object2.setShutdown(shutdown);
     }
     ...
 }
```

Comment: :- thanks gray..but exactly what i was asking was;could you suggest me  any other way to access all java application properties of an already existing java app with minimal source code changes.

Comment: What are "java application properties"?  I was trying to do that with my answer.

Comment: @Gray Liked the simple implementation of JMX.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you should express yourself more clearly. 
From what I understood - why not providing a way to query the remote application, and get information on all properties and if they are Read-only, Write-only or RW? 
This way the list of properties will not be mentioned at the source code of the client application - maybe you should let the user of the client application see the list of properties, and let him edit the properties he can edit, and prevent him from editing the properties he can't.

Comment: @zaske...from where can i fetch all the application properties?